# BDD solution testing of different layers outside-in

Tags: tdd, bdd, xunit.net

Recently, I got started reading on BDD and TDD and I got hooked. I got lost with the amount of unorganized sources of information and different opinions of what's best and what not. At the end I settled on [xBehave & xUnit](https://bitbucket.org/adamralph/xbehave.net/wiki/Home). I like the fluent syntax and the ease of defining the behaviors with Fluent Assertions and Fluent Validation.

I'm also trying to implement the onion architecture with a test project I'm working on for learning. Here's my scenario: The project, to make it simple, is a product tracker. I can create products and track who owns it. I want to implement two specs:

- when a new product is created without a name then an error should be displayed
- when a new product is created without an owner assigned then an error should be displayed.

I created the spec which instantiated a new Product and a new ProductService which in turns creates the Product. The spec passes and the validation is occuring now the question is:

1. How do I test my ProductRepository class? Do I test it next or mock it and finish all specs first then come back and test repository classes?
2. Should I have mocked the ProductService class in the first spec?
3. Is that done at the unit test level? should i create a unit test class?
4. Wouldn't testing the repository make it an integration test?

so far, I don't have a UI and i'm writing my specs for the domain, service, and infrastructure layers.

- do i need to use watin for my UI tests?
- would switching to watin/specflow makes more sense and would save on efforts to have fully tested layers from top to bottom?

Here's one of the specs I worked on:

```
[Scenario]
public void creating_new_product_without_a_name_should_throw_error()
{
    var productService = default(IProductService);
    var action = default(Action);
    _
        .Given("a new product", () =>
            productService = new ProductService() as IProductService)

        .When("creating the new product without a name", () =>
            action = () => productService.Create(new Product()))

        .Then("it should should display an error", () =>
            action.ShouldThrow<ValidationException("Name is required."));
}
```

Thank you for your reply in advance and, please, if you are answering this thread back up with some materials/articles/sample code on to why your suggestion would be better to follow.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are testing small parts and then plan to glue them together into something big. This is (IMO, againt) not TDD (and certainly not BDD): you are not letting the tests drive the design/architecture.

To start with, don't think that much about the design. Don't think onion architecture, don't think repositories, don't think services.

Start by writing a test that verifies the whole solution, from end to end. Make that test as small as possible. To start with, just verify that e.g. a label is displayed. Then write the smallest solution that you can think of to make the test pass. Then write another test and the solution for that.

After a while, have a look at the code (production, but also test) to find resposibilities. Is there an embryo of a service in there somewhere? Extract it! But don't do it prematurely. Let the code tell you what it wants to look like.

Start thinking about the domain (Product, Owner, etc) up front and include it early in your code. Wait a little longer with persistance (repositories), but not too long.

Keep testing at this level (end-to-end). Add micro tests when necessary. So my answer to the question "how do I test my ProductRepository/Service class" is a question to you: do you need to? Or is it sufficiently covered by the end-to-end tests? If not, why?

Comment: Sorry for not providing more information, I was being brief ... I did start initially with my test above. I didn't have anything else created. My test guided me to create my domain and service class, not the repository. After the test passed I move my classes and organized them into different layer, changed the references and the test passed again. That's why I asked the questions above. My tests are creating my domain and service layers, no UI, no Repositories yet. Do I go on like this then move to UI and Repos? or create my integration test now and setup my repos?

Comment: another thing, the bdd framework above is more on a unit level framework, so I can't test labels or UI yet which leads to my next question: would using specflow/watin duplicate my tests for the business layer? am i better off using specflow/watin instead of xbehave/xunit? (I would still use xUnit for my unit tests)

Comment: WOW ... I thought I would get bunch of replies on this matter :)